# Is there a way to create a pin (an annotation) on a MKMapView based on the current users location?

Tags: swift, xcode, mapkit, spotify

Overall I am trying to create an app that uses the Spotify API, the goal of the app is that based on the current song a user is listening to on Spotify on a press of a button the song is then mapped as a pin. I am currently stuck on trying to make a pin based on the users current location that stays there on the press of a button.

I have the code so far that it dynamically follows the user on MKMapView

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let regionInMeters: Double = 1000
    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkLocationServices()
    }


    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }


    func centerViewOnUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }


    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // Show alert letting the user know they have to turn this on.
        }
    }


    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            centerViewOnUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            // Show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }


    //    class pinedSong: NSObject , MKAnnotation {
    //        let title: String?
    //        let artist: String?
    //        let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    //
    //        init(title: String, artist: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    //        {
    //            self.title = title
    //            self.artist = artist
    //            self.coordinate = coordinate
    //
    //            super.init()
    //        }
    //    }
    //
    //
    //
    //
    //    @IBAction func btnPinSong(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //
    //
    //
    //
    //}
    //    func pinMaker(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    //        //Get Current Location
    //        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
    //        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    //        let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    //        myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    //        myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    //        mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
    //
    //    }
    //

}

extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }



}
```

For right now all I need working is for the button that places a pin based on the users current location that stays.

Comment: When you are working with mapkit, you can definitely show the user location. if you want to just pin it, it may make sense to get the user's location coordinates at a point in time and then create a pin rather than calling user location (which may update) Also, if you do use user location, make sure that you can show it:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locationManager.location` to get current users location.

```
@IBAction func btnPinSong(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Get Current Location
    guard let userLocation = self.locationManager.location else {
        return
    }

    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: If i am going to store these pins into a data base, what do you think the best way to do that would be?

Comment: If I were you, I'd use 
 Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint